# P/L sql String replace using CURSOR

Tags: plsql, substring

```
mystring := 'abc/dd/<parm1>kkk<parm2>.T<parm3>';
```

mycursor has parm1 parm2 and parm3 that param have value.

```
CURSOR mycursor IS

SELECT parm, value FROM &VIEW;
```

How can mystring parm`(<parm>)` replace value form the mycusor

After create new mystring it look like bellow(parm1 = value1, parm2 = value2, parm3 = value3)

```
mystring := 'abc/dd/value1kkkvalue2.Tvalue3';
```

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/replace.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
DECLARE
  mystring VARCHAR2(200) := 'abc/dd/<parm1>kkk<parm2>.T<parm3>';
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Before parameter replacement, mystring=''' ||
                       mystring || '''');

  FOR aRow IN (SELECT parm, value FROM SOME_VIEW) LOOP
    mystring := REPLACE(mystring, '<' || aRow.parm || '>', aRow.value);
  END LOOP;  -- aRow

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('After parameter replacement, mystring=''' ||
                       mystring || '''');
END;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Two problems: (a) `mystring` is missing the type (e.g. `VARCHAR2(100)`), (b) `REPLACE` is not a procedure or is undefined.